# Is it safe to use such smart pointer casting?

Tags: c++, casting, smart-pointers, tr1

Is it safe to use such smart pointer casting?

```
APtr a(new A());
BPtr & b = (Bptr&)a; // this is it
```

there,

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual ~A(){}
   virtual void methodA() = 0;
}
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<A> APtr;

class B : public A
{
public:
   virtual ~B(){}
   virtual void methodB() = 0;
}
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

BPtr & b = a; //this way doesn't work
```

Comment: Why not just use `BPtr b = a;`

Comment: @KennyTM: Not every A is a B. In fact, the A in question (`a`) most certainly isn't.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Oops sorry read the code as B being a base class of A.

Comment: @student023: Your `a` isn't an instance of a B, so what are you trying to accomplish by treating it as one?

Comment: ¤ The code you're showing won't compile. So the issue of safety is moot, or rather, it is entirely safe to *try*. Please ask about something that would compile.

Comment: -1 for posting code that cannot compile (even with trivial changes like adding `;`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To downcast a smart pointer, you should use the xxxx_pointer_cast functions, e.g. a [static cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982457.aspx)

```
BPtr b = std::tr1::static_pointer_cast<B>(a);
```

or [dynamic cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982967.aspx)

```
BPtr b = std::tr1::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is safe or not is another question. It is definitely unusual and not qutie possible to assign a smart to the reference of other type when also forcibly trying to make a dumb pointer of it.

I think you need to figure out what are these type first. And then. Well, the answer to your future question if you will insist on asking it will likely be "no".

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Revising this answer (since it is digged up again and a long time has passed).

Classes `A` and `B` might have an inheritance relation but `shared_ptr<A>` and `shared_ptr<B>` have not. `shared_ptr` is a template class and a template instantiation with `A` is in no relation with an instantiation with `B`.

Using C-like casting (or `reinterpret_cast`) works but only because you are enforcing a reinterpretation of the underlying bits. A `dynamic_cast` on two different `shared_ptr` instances will fail since you are not casting the inherited pointers but try to cast the smart pointers which are completely different and incompatible types.

For your asked question the answer is (still) no.

Comment: Never say never! Are you not familiar with why people use `dynamic_cast`?  I understand this is an old answer, but it's wrong too.

Comment: I stay with never. The original code is using a C-like cast which is more or less a reinterpret_cast on two distinct types. shared_ptr<A> is in no inheritance relation with shared_ptr<B> because of the nature of the template. That's why `BPtr & b = a; //this way doesn't work`. A dynamic_cast on the two typedefs should also fire an exception since BPtr and APtr are not in an inheritance relation.

Comment: I understand that the example given by the OP is a bad casting example. But you saying "never" doesn't qualify to a correct statement. Do I really need to state examples where you MUST cast to derived? Consider the case of the classical  `BaseAbstractClass* clone()` method. I just faced that case the other day with `QIconEngine` in Qt. You get the clone, which is basically of derived nature internally, but has base pointer type. If you don't cast it to derived, it's useless. I'm not saying you're wrong with the OP's case, but "NEVER" is a very strong word for this topic and doesn't apply.

Comment: Well true, i revised the answer. I was a little confused by the first two lines in the OP.